# Mixing controlled/uncontrolled behaviour with `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a component that displays a bunch of selectable options in a single row. It takes a `pageSize` prop from the parent component due to responsiveness requirements.

If the `pageSize` prop ever changes, I need to reset the `currentPage` (currently active page), which is held in state, to 0.

```
class OptionsRow extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        currentPage: 0
    }
    ...
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        // Reset page on pageSize change
        return {
            currentPage: props.pageSize === state.prevPageSize
                ? state.currentPage
                : 0,
            prevPageSize: props.pageSize
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This code works as intended.

The reason I'm asking for a review is that React in it's documentation warns against `getDerivedStateFromProps` so I'm not sure if this is a correct usage. In order to avoid derived state, it recommends making the component completely controlled/uncontrolled, so I should lift the `currentPage` up to the parent component. But is this really necessary? Is something wrong with my solution except for "[verbose code](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small and subtle issue with your usage of `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render
> method, both on the initial mount and ***on subsequent updates***. It should
> return an object to update the state, or ***null to update nothing***.

and

> Note that this method is fired on every render, regardless of the cause.

Your implementation returns a new state object every render regardless, but it should return null when nothing needs to be updated. By returning a new state object each render then unnecessary re-renders may occur in children components if passed any values from this component's state as they would fail shallow object comparison.

```
class OptionsRow extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    currentPage: 0
  }

  ...

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.pageSize !== state.prevPageSize) {
      // Reset page on pageSize change
      return {
        currentPage: 0,
        prevPageSize: props.pageSize
      }
    }

    // Nothing changed, return null to keep existing state
    return null;
  }

  ...

}
```

***However***, in 3+ years working with react I've not ever had any compelling reason to reach for `getDerivedStateFromProps` and the docs even specify

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on
> changes in props ***over time***.

The last bit bolded is the important bit. Your component's behavior appears to simply be an effect of a prop updating, i.e. a side-effect to reset state, and *could* be implemented via the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

### Solution 1 - Bronze

```
class OptionsRow extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    currentPage: 0,
  }

  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Reset page on pageSize change
    if (this.props.pageSize !== prevState.prevPageSize) {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: 0,
        prevPageSize: this.props.pageSize,
      });
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

But notice now that the state `currentPage` only needs to be reset when `props.pageSize` updates, so you can directly compare current and previous props and drop the storage of the "last" pageSize in local component state.

### Solution 2 - Silver

```
class OptionsRow extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    currentPage: 0,
  }

  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Reset page on pageSize change
    if (this.props.pageSize !== prevProps.pageSize) {
      this.setState({ currentPage: 0 });
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

There is still room for improvement though, using the third bullet point from the docs.

> If you want to **“reset” some state when a prop changes**, consider either
> making a component fully controlled or [fully uncontrolled with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)
> instead.

What this means is you can completely forego the `getDerivedStateFromProps` ***and*** `componentDidUpdate` logic to check and compare the props' `pageSize` value and simply use a react key that updates when the pageSize does.

> When a `key` changes, React will [*create* a new component instance rather
> than *update* the current one](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

### Solution 3 - Gold

```
<OptionsRow key={pageSize} pageSize={pageSize} />
```

[image: Edit mixing-controlled-uncontrolled-behaviour-with-getderivedstatefromprops]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for explanation. I completely forgot about the `key` thing, very nice solution indeed.